# memcpy using local pointer to global data

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, global-variables

I have a global structure called xbar. I calloc 3 of these, and then pass a local pointer to a function where it is assigned to a short array inside the global function.  But then when I try to use memcpy to copy the pointed-to data, I get an "exception" error.

```
typedef struct s_xbar
{
    short close[390][9000];
} xbar;
xbar *Xbar;

void assignPtr(short *qdata)
{
    qdata = Xbar[0].close[0];
}

void mycode( void )
{
    Xbar      =  (xbar  *)  calloc( 3,  sizeof(xbar));  

    short *qdata = NULL;
    assignPtr(qdata);

    short dataBarToFill[500];
    memcpy(dataBarToFill, qdata, 90 *  sizeof(short));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because in `assignPtr()` you only assigned `Xbar[0].close[0]` to a *local copy* of pointer `qdata`. After `assignPtr()` returns, the `qdata` in `mycode()` is still NULL.
You should pass in pointer-to-pointer like the following:

```
void assignPtr(short **qdata)
{
    *qdata = Xbar[0].close[0];
}

void mycode( void )
{
    Xbar      =  (xbar  *)  calloc( 3,  sizeof(xbar));  

    short *qdata = NULL;
    assignPtr(&qdata);

    short dataBarToFill[500];
    memcpy(dataBarToFill, qdata, 90 *  sizeof(short));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C is a pass-by-value language, so you should pass the address of `qdata`:

```
void assignPtr(short **qdata)
{
    *qdata = Xbar[0].close[0];
}

void mycode( void )
{
    Xbar      =  (xbar  *)  calloc( 3,  sizeof(xbar));  

    short *qdata = NULL;
    assignPtr(&qdata);
    // ...
}
```